# Recursive function for computing the quantity of (n! mod M)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, factorial

Does anyone know a method for computing the quantity of

```
n! mod M
```

such that overflow is not an issue? I cannot think of anything where such a large value of n would not cause a problem.

Comment: Well, I didn't until I did a search with google ;) [Stack Overflow: How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `n * (n-1)` does not overflow, you can just take the product `mod M` after every multiplication.

**Update**: As  `Dukeling` very patiently explained to me, the assumption above is not a **sufficient** condition to **ensure** that method of applying `mod M` after each multiplication will guarantee no overflow.

The **sufficient** condition is that `(M-1)*(n mod M)` does not overflow, because that is the largest possible product that could result  before the `mod` is taken.

Comment: It should be more like `(M-1)*(n mod M)` that shouldn't overflow. Consider `5! mod 30` with an overflow at `50`. `5*4 << 50`, yet it overflows.

Comment: The biggest number you can get `mod M` is `M-1`. `M` should also be fine. For a more exact bound you can probably replace `n` by `n-1` as well.

Comment: `M-1` is the biggest number, thus also the biggest product, that can exist post-mod, multiplying that by the biggest single number `n`, gives you the biggest product pre-mod.

Comment: @Dukeling, Please write a separate answer. I am not following how finding the biggest product pre-mod is going to enable you to compute `n!`.

Comment: I don't think I can explain it much better than I already did. I was just pointing out that `n * (n-1)` in your answer is wrong and should be `(M-1)*(n mod M)` instead - it's not an answer in itself, it's a correction to yours.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51842/discussion-between-merlin2011-and-dukeling)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Big Integer library, it will never overflow.  However, depending on the algorithm and the number of digits you want, it might take years to execute.